# Directory architecture for admin and website in React Js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have web site in react js. My current directory structure is

```
view -> partials | includes | components -> all this folder includes jsx files  
vendors -> js and css files  
node_modules   
model -> db connection files  
assets -> images | fonts  
config -> some json config files  
webpack.config.js  
package.json  
main.jsx  
index.html
```

Now I need to implement admin panel under above project. I'm not sure how to maintain architecture for admin panel and web site both in single service.

Is it I need to maintain different directory and service for admin or can I implement both admin and website in same project in above listed directory ?